# Return value from Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

How to return a `String` value from an `Optional<String>` using `ifPresent` and avoiding `NullPointerException`?

Example:

```
public String longestName() {
    Optional<String> longName = someList.stream().reduce((name1, name2) -> name1.length() > name2.length() ? name1 : name2);

    // If I do not want to use following
    // return longName.isPresent() ? longName.get() : "not present";

    // Can I achieve this using longName.ifPresent or longName.orElse("not present");
}
```

Comment: another way I can do something like this,                                                       
 return someList.stream().reduce("default value", (n1, n2) -> n1.length() > n2.length() ? n1 : n2);

 but I was looking if there is any way to return String value 
  Optional<String> longName = someList.stream().reduce((n1, n2) -> n1.length() > n2.length() ? n1 : n2);
  return longName.ifPresent()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To return the value of an optional, or a default value if the optional has no value, you can use [`orElse(other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-).

```
public String longestName() {
    Optional<String> longNameOpt = someList.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
    return longNameOpt.orElse("not present");
}
```

Note that I rewrote your code for finding the longest name: you can directly use [`max(comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) with a comparator comparing the length of each String. One such comparator can be obtained by calling [`Comparator.comparingInt(keyExtractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) with the key extractor being the method reference `String::length`.

Comment: return longNameOpt.orElse("not present"); was something I was looking for. Thanks